# handle number format exception

Tags: android

when i am getting data after xml parsing and use it in my application i am getting number format exception so i add try and catch block between that code and now it is not force close  but the problem is that after getting the exception it does not execute the code after that how to get over again and it takes some default value for it and execute for next 
my code is below pls modify in my catch block...

```
   for(int i=0;i<sitesList.getLatitude().size();i++)
    {
            if(sitesList.getType().get(i).equalsIgnoreCase("Galerías Online"))
            {
             name = sitesList.getLatitude().get(i);
                 name1 = sitesList.getLongitude().get(i);

            GeoPoint  point5 = new GeoPoint((int) (Double.parseDouble(name) * 1E6),
                        (int) (Double.parseDouble(name1) * 1E6));
            OverlayItem  overlayItem4 = new OverlayItem(point5, sitesList.getGalleryname().get(i)+ "--"+ 
                     sitesList.getAddress().get(i),sitesList.getImagesurl().get(i)+ "--"+sitesList.getEmail().get(i)+ "--"+
                     sitesList.getPhoneno().get(i)+ "--"+sitesList.getWeb().get(i) );
            itemizedOverlay3.addOverlay(overlayItem4);

        }
        }
        }catch (NumberFormatException e) {

        }
```

**means it continue for loop after getting exception and use default value in place of exception..i am getting exception here    name = sitesList.getLatitude().get(i);
                     name1 = sitesList.getLongitude().get(i);and i want to continue after exception how to do this ..i am new in java**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting null or empty values in your tag then, modify your code like this:

```
if(sitesList.getType().get(i).equalsIgnoreCase("Galerías Online"))
        {
         name = sitesList.getLatitude().get(i);
             name1 = sitesList.getLongitude().get(i);
          if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("")||name.equalsIgnoreCase(null))
          {
             name=// your default longitude or latitude
           }

          if(name1.equalsIgnoreCase("")||name1.equalsIgnoreCase(null))
          {
             name1=// your default longitude or latitude
           }
           ....
   }
```

hope it helps

Comment: hi jaydeep ...i am  getting number format exception ...latitutde and longitude tag which contains no value it takes by default upper tag value that is in string so throwing number format exception ..i appreciate ur above suugetion pls solve this problem

Comment: In place of name enter the default value manually e.g:-name="123456";

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0;i<sitesList.getLatitude().size();i++)
    {
            if(sitesList.getType().get(i).equalsIgnoreCase("Galerías Online"))
            {
             name = sitesList.getLatitude().get(i);
                 name1 = sitesList.getLongitude().get(i);

            GeoPoint  point5 = new GeoPoint( (Double.parseDouble(name) * 1E6),
                         (Double.parseDouble(name1) * 1E6));
            OverlayItem  overlayItem4 = new OverlayItem(point5, sitesList.getGalleryname().get(i)+ "--"+ 
                     sitesList.getAddress().get(i),sitesList.getImagesurl().get(i)+ "--"+sitesList.getEmail().get(i)+ "--"+
                     sitesList.getPhoneno().get(i)+ "--"+sitesList.getWeb().get(i) );
            itemizedOverlay3.addOverlay(overlayItem4);

        }
        }
        }catch (NumberFormatException e) {

        }
```

its because u r casting Double to Int...

Comment: hi...the problem is data coming from server means data coming from web service contains tag as latitude and longitude but in some place it is empty ,no value in the tag of lat and long and when i store it in array after parsing and want to show it in map it creates problem so i want where lat long value is null i show default position at that place and continue for the next loop value so i asked how to continue after exception occur?

Comment: i think problem is no on casting double to int name and name1 is string type of variable only

Comment: pls help me for over come my prblem

Comment: Make sure Server is not returning null and rather than parsing value to double.. parse it to Long directly...